# Create Monad Instance of empty list

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have the following functions:

```
def map2[F[_]: Monad, A,B,C](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])(f: (A,B) => C): F[C] =
  for {
    v1 <- fa
    v2 <- fb
  } yield f(v1,v2)

def sequence[M[_]: Monad, A](lma: List[M[A]]): M[List[A]] =
  lma.foldRight(List.empty[A].point[M])((z,a) => map2(z,a)(_::_))
```

Is there a more idomatic scalaz method of creating an instance of

```
List.empty[A].point[M]
```

I have tried `Nil.point[M]` but that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nil[A].point[M]`, where `nil` is a method provided by Scalaz as an alternative to `Nil` with a more appropriate type. I guess you could call it more idiomatic, but in my book `List.empty[A]` is perfectly fine.